# Select random rows from table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, select, random, newid

I want to select 24 Random rows from whole table of Admin_Pic_Lib, but 
this Query give syntax error,

```
 SELECT top 24 CAST( [Pictures] AS varbinary(Max)) FROM Admin_Pic_Lib ORDER BY NEWID()

 UNION ALL 

  SELECT  CAST([Pictures] AS varbinary(Max))   FROM User_images  WHERE UserName ='ahmed'
```

When I am trimming `ORDER BY NEWID()` it only select top 24 rows.

Comment: AFAIK `TOP` is applied _after_ `ORDER BY` happens.  So the top half of your `UNION` query should already be returning 24 random rows.  Can you elaborate on what you are seeing and why you think there is a problem?

Comment: Also tag the relevant RDBMS you  are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the below code.

```
SELECT Pictures 
FROM 
    (SELECT TOP 24 CAST([Pictures] AS varbinary(Max)) AS Pictures 
     FROM Admin_Pic_Lib ORDER BY NEWID()) AS X

 UNION ALL 

  SELECT  CAST([Pictures] AS varbinary(Max)) AS Pictures 
  FROM User_images
  WHERE UserName ='ahmed'
```